# Как проверить есть ли NULL в списке?

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день. Подскажите как проверить наличие `NULL` в списке?
Например есть список

```
2016-09-01
2016-09-02
NULL
2016-09-05
```

Как проверить есть ли в списке `NULL`, но сделать это надо в блоке `SELECT` без `WHERE`!

Comment: Проверить и... Сделать что? Какое должно в SELECT попасть значение?

Comment: Любое!! Например 1 если есть NULL

Comment: Пока не понятно, как должен выглядеть результат. Приведенные значения - то строки или поля?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(pole IS NULL, 1, 0)) count_null FROM table
```

Если **count_null** > 0, то в таблице есть NULL

Работает следующим способом:

Аггрегирующая функция SUM складывает все значения которая выдает функция IF и выдает одну строку по всем записям в таблице (аггрегирующая функция всегда выдает одну запись на всю таблицу ну или на группу)

IF(pole IS NULL, 1, 0) - Если pole равно NULL, тогда вернуть 1, если не равно, тогда вернуть 0.

Так вот, эта конструкция перебирает построчно таблицу, берет каждую строку и если есть NULL, то IF выдает значение 1 и SUM суммирует по сути количество NULL в таблице по всем строкам.

Comment: ДА!!! Это оно!! Хотя я не очень понимаю как это работает!

А нет Сообразил! Как я не догадался!

Comment: @АлександрРублев Попробовал описать Вам устройство данной конструкции в посте.

Comment: Я понял спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Для проверки значения на `NULL` существует специальная конструкция `IS NULL` (и `IS NOT NULL`). Можно воспользоваться ей

```
SELECT
  IF(fld IS NULL, '1', fld)
FROM
  tbl
```

Кроме того, существует стандартная функция `COALESCE()`, которая принимает произвольное количество аргументов и возвращает первое не NULL-значение. К ней тоже часто прибегают, чтобы присвоить NULL-значениям какое-то другое значение

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(fld, '1')
FROM
  tbl
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(1)-count(date) from table
```

Даст количество NULL значений в колонке `date`. Работает за счет того, что функция `count()` считает количество НЕ NULL значений в колонке. `count(1)` даст общее количество записей в таблице, `count(date)` количество НЕ NULL. В отличии от IF работает на любых SQL базах.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `COUNT` считает количество не `NULL` значений в колонке. То есть, надо просто "перевернуть" значения в колонке с `NULL` на что-то, а что-то на `NULL`:

```
create table tab (col int);
insert into tab
values (1), (2), (null), (3), (null);

select count(1) total, count(case when col is null then 1 end) nulls  
from tab;

|total |nulls |
+------+------+
|    5 |    2 |
```

Это решение соответствует стандарту SQL. На [sql<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7f0d021bcee92a6e0b765b30bf85cb8).